# Start browser in non-icognito to preserve login

Tags: node.js, webautomation, playwright

I don't want to automate the login for the site I'm testing using Playwright.

Is it possible to start browser in non-icognito to preserve login? If not, what are the options

Answer (score 2):

You can use [launchPersistent](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/master/docs/api.md#browsertypelaunchpersistentcontextuserdatadir-options) passing a `userDataDir` argument:

```js
const browserContext = await chromium.launchPersistentContext(userDataDir);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess your web app login was based on cookies.

So if you want to prevent the browser auto-login, you need to delete the saved identity cookie.

As the document mentioned:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

> Expires= Optional
> The maximum lifetime of the cookie as an HTTP-date timestamp. See Date for the required formatting.
>
> If unspecified, the cookie becomes a session cookie. A session finishes when the client shuts down, and session cookies will be removed.

When you are setting the cookie which you don't want to keep it when browser restarts, do NOT set the `Expires` attribute.

And your cookie will become a `session cookie` like this:

[image: session cookie]

After you re-open your browser, your sign-in status will be lost automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to tell playwright not to open using icognito? If there is, if I login manually once (I run with headless disabled), wouldn't it keep the cookies?